# Multiply input value by data-value and then sum the results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nine inputs text and I need to multiply the input value by data-value of each input and then sum the results and display ir on the div.

Input value-1 **x** data-value-1 
+ 
Input value-2 **x** data-value-2 
+ 
Input value-3 **x** data-value-3

... until 9

My code and how far I've gotten:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/erickcouto/8mkru0s8/6/)**

```js
$(function() {
      $('.insert').on('keydown', '.quantity-input', function(e){-1!==$.inArray(e.keyCode,[46,8,9,27,13,110,190])||/65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode)&&(!0===e.ctrlKey||!0===e.metaKey)||35<=e.keyCode&&40>=e.keyCode||(e.shiftKey||48>e.keyCode||57<e.keyCode)&&(96>e.keyCode||105<e.keyCode)&&e.preventDefault()});
    })
    

$(".quantity-input").change(function(){
if($(this).val()=="") $(this).val(0);
  var total = 0;
  $(".quantity-input").each(function(index,element){
    if ($(element).val()) {
      total+= parseInt($(element).val());
    }
  });
  $(".subtotal strong").text(total);
});

$('.quantity-input').keyup(function(event) {
  var b = $(this).val();
  var c = $(this).data('value');
  var d = b * c
  alert(d)
 });
```

```css
table
{
  width: 100%;
}
table th
{
  text-align: center;
}
table td
{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
}
table td input
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subtotal" colspan="9">subtotal: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="total" colspan="9">Total: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the difference between subtotal and total? Is subtotal just the sum, and total the sum of the multiplication?

Comment: Your inputs have `data-value="5"` same data value?? .. and you have 2 change event for the same element??

Comment: Always use keyup instead of keydown if you want to use the newly input text in the function. Otherwise the function will run before the input is applied

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon subtotal just sum of the all input values and total sum of the all `(input value * data-value`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes the data-value are equal for all the inputs, I'll get this value by back-end. I put 5 just to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple I used `input` event for the input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity-input").on('input',function(){
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $(".quantity-input").each(function(index,element){
      if ($(element).val()) {
        subtotal += parseInt($(element).val());
        total += parseInt($(element).val()) * parseInt($(element).data('value'));
      }

    });
    $(".subtotal strong").text(subtotal);
      $(".total strong").text(total);
  });
});
```

```css
table
{
  width: 100%;
}
table th
{
  text-align: center;
}
table td
{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
}
table td input
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subtotal" colspan="9">subtotal: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="total" colspan="9">Total: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Additional Information** you can combine event functions `input` ,`change` ... etc
>
> like `$(".quantity-input").on('input change',function(){`

Comment: If there is no need to include the HTML and CSS since they have nothing to do with the question or answer, should you not leave it out? It makes the answer neater and more pleasant to read.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon live demo is always win .. and while [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) just let us show and hide all the code snippet not just the part of it so I'm showing the demo with all parts

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't see it was a live demo as I am on the app which doesn't yet support it. Sorry ;)

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon never mind , You're welcome.. but you know .. its really a good idea to show just the working part and hide unneeded parts while keep the live demo on ..  may you contact SO with this one or may they update it in the future .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to on change of an input, you update the subtotal and total.

inside the  `$(".quantity-input").each` subtotal will be the sum of all input, and total will be all input with correspond data-value.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.insert').on('keydown', '.quantity-input', function(e) {
    -1 !== $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) || /65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode) && (!0 === e.ctrlKey || !0 === e.metaKey) || 35 <= e.keyCode && 40 >= e.keyCode || (e.shiftKey || 48 > e.keyCode || 57 < e.keyCode) && (96 > e.keyCode || 105 < e.keyCode) && e.preventDefault()
  });
})

$('.quantity-input').on('change', function(event) {
  if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val(0);
  var subtotal = 0;
  var total = 0;
  $(".quantity-input").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).val()) {
      subtotal += parseInt($(element).val());
      total += parseInt($(element).val() * $(this).data('value'));
    }
  });
  $(".subtotal > strong").text(subtotal);
  $(".total > strong").text(total);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
}

table td input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
      <td class="insert"><input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subtotal" colspan="9">subtotal: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="total" colspan="9">Total: <strong>00</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.insert').on('keydown', '.quantity-input', function(e) {
        -1 !== $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) || /65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode) && (!0 === e.ctrlKey || !0 === e.metaKey) || 35 <= e.keyCode && 40 >= e.keyCode || (e.shiftKey || 48 > e.keyCode || 57 < e.keyCode) && (96 > e.keyCode || 105 < e.keyCode) && e.preventDefault()
    });
})


$(".quantity-input").on('keyup', function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val(0);

    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0; // accounts for data attr values 
    $(".quantity-input").each(function(index, element) {
        element = $(element);
        if (element.val()) {
            subtotal += parseInt(element.val());
            total += parseInt(element.val()) * element.data('value');
        }
    });
    $(".subtotal strong").text(subtotal);
    $(".total strong").text(total);
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table th {
    text-align: center;
}

table td {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 10%;
}

table td input {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
            <td class="insert">
                <input type="text" class="quantity-input" data-value="5" value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="subtotal" colspan="9">subtotal: <strong>00</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="total" colspan="9">Total: <strong>00</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reading your code... But I found it quite confusing and awkward. This code should produce the described outcome. Hope it helps :)

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0,
    d = 0;

$(".quantity-input").keyup(function(){
    $(".quantity-input").each(function(){
        // a holds value of input
        a = parseInt($(this).val()); 
        // b holds multiple of value and data-value
        b = a * $(this).data("value");
        console.log(b);
        // c holds subtotal
        c += a;
        // d holds total
        d += b;
    });
    $(".subtotal strong").html(c);
    $(".total strong").html(d);
});
```